# Two <img> without spacing

Tags: html, css, image

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
  <title>HAHAHA</title>
  <STYLE TYPE="text/css" media="screen">
  *
  {
   padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
   body
   {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
   }
   #flexbox
   {
    //display: -webkit-box;
    //-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    //-webkit-box-align: stretch;
    //width: auto;
   }
  </STYLE>
 </head>
 <BODY style="padding:0;margin:0;border:0;">
  <!--<div id="flexbox">
   <img src="1.jpg" width="100px" style="padding:0;margin:0;"/>
   <img src="1.jpg" width="100px"/>
   <img src="1.jpg" width="100px"/>
  </div>-->
  <img src="http://is.gd/kjxtj" style="padding:0;margin:0;border:0;"/>
   <img src="http://is.gd/kjxtj" style="padding:0;margin:0;border:0;"/>
 </BODY>
</html>
```

Why do these images always have a small space in between them, even if i have padding & margin set to 0 on body and all other elements in page?

OK this is the full unedited code.

EDIT: just found out its the line break between the two IMG.
SO... i cannot press enter between the two  elements? lol... :)

Comment: can you give us your css code?

Comment: it's not like that per your code alone: http://jsbin.com/atigu5 - code you haven't shown us is causing the problem

Comment: you have made sure the images don't have some kind of border in the actual image...

Comment: It should not have any space in between AFAIK, even without any CSS. Can you create a small sample page where the problem occurs?

Comment: make img border to 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

images are displayed `inline` by default, which is likely your issue. White-space characters in HTML are condensed, however they will still appear as a space if any exist between HTML elements.

The following HTML will render with a slight space between images.

```
<div class="images">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" />
</div>
```

If you'd like to make them flush against each other, you could try floating the images:

```
img {
  float: left;
}
```

Floating comes with its own issues if you're new to CSS.

An alternative is to adjust the markup to get rid of extra white-space characters. A common way to do this is called "fishy" syntax:

```
<div class="images"
    ><img src="http://placehold.it/400x300"
    /><img src="http://placehold.it/400x300"
/></div>
```

The way it works is that the closing `>` character of each element is moved to just before the beginning `<` character such that there's no white-space within any HTML element as content. Instead, the white-spaces for indentation are within the HTML tags, where the white-space is ignored completely.

There was a [w3c feature request for a new property on `white-space`](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2013Mar/0718.html), which could theoretically allow CSS to remove *all* spaces from an element. The orignal proposal was `white-space: ignore;` however I much prefer (and suggested) `white-space: none;`.

It appears, however, that updating `white-space` is not likely to happen, and instead the suggestion was to use flexbox to remove spaces appropriately:

<sub>extending off the original HTML example:</sub>

```
.images {
    display: flex;
}
```

Of course, it will be some time before flexbox has enough cross-browser support to be useful in a commercial environment, so for the time being I recommend sticking with the fishy syntax.

Comment: This is the most complete answer when i reviewed after quite some time. And also I would like to add to your answer that there's "inline-block" which seems the most correct to my initial question.

Answer (score 6):

> i cannot press enterin between the two elements? lol... :)

Nothing distinguishes one type of white space from another in most parts of HTML.

You can, however, format your code such:

```
<img src="..." alt="..."
><img src="..." alt="...">
```

… to remove the space between the elements.

Comment: Thanks, still it seems to me so weird :)

Answer (score 3):

There's a good trick to overcome this:

Place your images inside a `<div>` and then set

`font-size:0px;`

to the `<div>`.

You can continue keeping the  elements on separate lines.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is also necessary if you are viewing in an older version of IE

```
img {
    border:0
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

While I think the problem is coming from another point in your mark-up, and/or CSS, I would suggest ensuring that you've zeroed out both `margin`, `padding` and `border` for the `img` element:

```
img {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border-width: 0;
}
```

This *should* take care of the problem, but if not we may need to see your real html and css (or a live demo that reproduces the problem, at [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com), or [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)) to help you further.